# jquery hide parent tag when a-tag contains "_sk"

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
    <div id="secondary">
        <ul class="simple-pages-navigation">
            <li class="nav-das-projekt current"><a href="/projekt">Das Projekt</a>
                <ul class="subnav-1">
                    <li class="nav-ber-kaschau"><a href="/ber-kaschau">Über Kaschau</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-projektpartner"><a href="/projektpartner">Projektpartner</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-projektu"><a href="/projekt_sk">Projekt</a>
                <ul class="subnav-1">
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/ber-kaschau_sk">O Košiciach</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/partneri_sk">O Košiciach</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-project"><a href="/projekt_en">Project</a>
                <ul class="subnav-1">
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/ber-kaschau_en">About Kaschau</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/partner_en">Project Partners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

I want to add css `display:none;` via jQuery to all parent-parent tags whose daughter-tags have a link ending with `"_sk"` or `"_en"` in it.
the result should look like this:

    <div id="secondary">
        <ul class="simple-pages-navigation">
            <li class="nav-das-projekt current"><a href="/projekt">Das Projekt</a>
                <ul class="subnav-1">
                    <li class="nav-ber-kaschau"><a href="/ber-kaschau">Über Kaschau</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-projektpartner"><a href="/projektpartner">Projektpartner</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-projektu" style="display: none"><a href="/projekt_sk">Projekt</a>
                <ul class="subnav-1">
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/ber-kaschau_sk">O Košiciach</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/partneri_sk">O Košiciach</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-project" style="display: none"><a href="/projekt_en">Project</a>
                <ul class="subnav-1">
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/ber-kaschau_en">About Kaschau</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-o-koiciach"><a href="/partner_en">Project Partners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

=== Edit: ===

I add some more HTML and now the answer

```
$('a[href$="_sk"], a[href$="_hu"]').parent().hide();
```

doesn't work at this html-code and i can't figure out why because it works still for a-tag-links ending with "_sk" but not for the ones with "_hu":

```
<div id="secondary">
    <ul class="simple-pages-navigation">
        <li class="nav-a-projekt"><a href="/projekt_hu">A Projekt</a>
            <ul class="subnav-1">
                <li class="nav-difmoe" style="display: list-item;"><a href="/difmoe_hu">DiFMOE ,</a></li>
                <li class="nav-kassrl" style="display: list-item;"><a href="/ber-kaschau_hu">Kassáról</a></li>
                <li class="nav-projektpartnerek" style="display: list-item;"><a href="/projektpartner_hu">Projektpartnerek</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-das-projekt current"><a href="/projekt_de">Das Projekt</a>
            <ul class="subnav-1">
                <li class="nav-ber-kaschau"><a href="/ber-kaschau_de">Über Kaschau</a></li>
                <li class="nav-projektpartner"><a href="/projektpartner_de">Projektpartner</a></li>
                <li class="nav-difmoe"><a href="/difmoe_de">DiFMOE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-die-digitale-stadtbibliothek" style="display: none;"><a href="http://cassovia-digitalis.eu/">Die Digitale Stadtbibliothek</a></li>
        <li class="nav-die-digitale-stadtbibliothek---en" style="display: none;"><a href="/startseite_en">Die Digitale Stadtbibliothek - EN</a></li>
        <li class="nav-die-digitale-stadtbibliothek---hu" style="display: none;"><a href="/startseite_hu">Die Digitale Stadtbibliothek - HU</a></li>
        <li class="nav-die-digitale-stadtbibliothek---sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/startseite_sk">Die Digitale Stadtbibliothek - SK</a></li>
        <li class="nav-projekt" style="display: none;"><a href="/projekt_sk">Projekt</a>
            <ul class="subnav-1">
                <li class="nav-o-koiciach" style="display: none;"><a href="/ber-kaschau_sk">O Košiciach</a></li>
                <li class="nav-partneri-projektu" style="display: none;"><a href="/projektpartner_sk">Partneri projektu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-difmoe" style="display: none;"><a href="/difmoe_sk">DiFMOE .</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-bibliothek"><a href="/bibliothek_de">Bibliothek</a>
            <ul class="subnav-1">
                <li class="nav-periodika"><a href="/periodika_de">Periodika</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-zeitungen"><a href="/zeitungen_de">Zeitungen</a>
                            <ul class="subnav-3" style="display: none;">
                                <li class="nav-felsmagyarorszag"><a href="/felsoemagyarorszag">Felsömagyarorszag</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-kaschau-eperieser-kundschaftsblatt"><a href="/kundschaftsblatt_de">Kaschau-Eperieser Kundschaftsblatt</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-kassai-szemle"><a href="/kassai-szemle_de">Kassai Szemle</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-zeitschriften"><a href="/zeitschriften_de">Zeitschriften</a>
                            <ul class="subnav-3" style="display: none;">
                                <li class="nav-der-bote-von-und-fr-ungern"><a href="/bote-ungarn_de">Der Bote von und für Ungern</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-pannonia"><a href="/pannonia_de">Pannonia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-volkskalender"><a href="/volkskalender_de">Volkskalender</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-bcher"><a href="/monographien_de">Bücher</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-gesamtliste"><a href="/monographien_sortdate">Gesamtliste</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-bildersammlung"><a href="/bildersammlung_de">Bildersammlung</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-postkarten"><a href="/postkarten_de">Postkarten</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-karten"><a href="/karten_de">Karten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-sondersammlungen"><a href="/sondersammlung">Sondersammlungen</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-alltag"><a href="/alltag_de">Alltag</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-eugen-deil"><a href="/eugen-deil_de">Eugen Deil</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-theaterplakate"><a href="/theaterplakate_de">Theaterplakate</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-handwerk"><a href="/wanderbuecher_de">Handwerk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-adressbcher"><a href="/adressbuecher_de">Adressbücher</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-kninica" style="display: none;"><a href="/bibliothek_sk">Knižnica</a>
            <ul class="subnav-1">
                <li class="nav-periodik" style="display: none;"><a href="/periodika_sk">Periodiká.</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-zeitungen_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/zeitungen_sk">Zeitungen_sk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-zeitschriften_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/zeitschriften_sk">Zeitschriften_sk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-volkskalender_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/volkskalender_sk">Volkskalender_sk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-knihy" style="display: none;"><a href="/monographien_sk">Knihy</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-gesamtliste_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/monographien_sortdate_sk">Gesamtliste_sk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-obrazov-materil" style="display: none;"><a href="/bildersammlung_sk">Obrazový materiál</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-postkarten_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/postkarten_sk">Postkarten_sk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-karten_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/karten_sk">Karten_sk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-pecilne-zbierky" style="display: none;"><a href="/sondersammlung_sk">Špeciálne zbierky</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-alltag_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/alltag_sk">Alltag_sk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-theaterplakate_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/theaterplakate_sk">Theaterplakate_sk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-eugen-deil" style="display: none;"><a href="/eugen-deil_sk">Eugen Deil.</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-handwerk_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/wanderbuecher_sk">Handwerk_sk</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-adressbcher_sk" style="display: none;"><a href="/adressbuecher_sk">Adressbücher_sk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-knyvtr" style="display: list-item;"><a href="/bibliothek_hu">Könyvtár</a>
            <ul class="subnav-1">
                <li class="nav-idszaki-kiadvnyok" style="display: list-item;"><a href="/periodika_hu">Időszaki kiadványok</a>
                    <ul class="subnav-2">
                        <li class="nav-zeitungen_hu" style="display: list-item;"><a href="/zeitungen_hu">Zeitungen_hu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('a[href$="_sk"], a[href$="_en"]').parent().hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uH964/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use $ in jQuery selector to get link ends with.

> Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$="value"]`
>
> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

**Example**

```
$('a[href$="_sk"]').css('display','none');
```

Comment: how can i add the css two levels higher (to the <li class="nav-projekt">)?

Comment: @Lennier so you can use `$('a[href$="_sk"]').parent('li');`